# nsolve решение нелинейных уравнений

Tags: python, sympy

Заполняю динамически массив аргументов и функций, где N+1 это кол-во уравнений, аргументов:

```
a = [0]*(N+1)
f = [0]*(N+1)
i = 0
while i < (N + 1):
    a[i] = Symbol(('a'+chr(48+i)))
    f[i] = -R[i]
    i = i + 1
m = 0
while m < (N+1):
    i = 0
    while i <= N - m:
        f[m] = f[m] + a[i]*a[i+m]
        i = i + 1
    m = m + 1
print(f, a)
```

показывает:

```
[a0**2 + a1**2 - 332.236351096697, a0*a1 - 106.241697077312] [a0, a1]
```

хочу решить эту систему с помощью nsolve:

```
nsolve(f, a, [1]*(N+1))
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Артем/PycharmProjects/tsp/tsp/tsp.py", line 158, in <module>
    print(ss_n(R[:2], 1))
  File "C:/Users/Артем/PycharmProjects/tsp/tsp/tsp.py", line 118, in ss_n
    return nsolve(f, a, [1]*(N+1))
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\tsp\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\decorator.py", line 91, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\tsp\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 2847, in nsolve
    x = findroot(f, x0, J=J, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\tsp\venv\lib\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\optimization.py", line 960, in findroot
    for x, error in iterations:
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\tsp\venv\lib\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\optimization.py", line 658, in __iter__
    s = self.ctx.lu_solve(Jx, fxn)
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\tsp\venv\lib\site-packages\mpmath\matrices\linalg.py", line 227, in lu_solve
    A, p = ctx.LU_decomp(A)
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\tsp\venv\lib\site-packages\mpmath\matrices\linalg.py", line 152, in LU_decomp
    raise ZeroDivisionError('matrix is numerically singular')
ZeroDivisionError: matrix is numerically singular
```

Answer (score 1):

Для заданных параметров при решении возникает ошибка деления на ноль...

С "правильными" параметрами все работает:

```
In [107]: nsolve(funcs, (a0, a1), [1,0])
Out[107]:
Matrix([
[17.1412006550957],
[6.19803123567827]])
```

чтобы найти все решения можно воспользоваться `solve`:

```
In [151]: solutions = solve(funcs, [a0, a1])

In [152]: solutions
Out[152]:
[(-17.1412006550957, -6.19803123567827),
 (-6.19803123567827, -17.1412006550957),
 (6.19803123567827, 17.1412006550957),
 (17.1412006550957, 6.19803123567827)]

In [153]: nsolve(funcs, [a0, a1], solutions[0])
Out[153]:
Matrix([
[-17.1412006550957],
[-6.19803123567827]])
```

Comment: вы знаете как можно подобрать оптимальные параметры?

Comment: @j6wj1997, дайте определение для "оптимальные параметры". Вы пытаетесь решить систему нелинейных уравнений? Если да то добавьте в вопрос сами уравнения (в виде уравнений)...

Comment: Уравнения составляются в зависимости от параметра N, чем больше тем больше уравнений , составляются по тексту программы